# Как в игре сделать ввод с клавиатуры?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Хотел в своей игре сделать ввод имени персонажа. Как можно это сделать?

(Похоже, в этом должен помочь InputField, но не понял, как им пользоваться. Делать свою клавиатуру через Input.GetKeyDown кажется очень глупой идеей)

Comment: А что вы не поняли в InputField?

Answer (score 2):

[InputField](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2018.4/Manual/script-InputField.html) - это UI элемент, по-русски - текстовое поле, и это лучший способ сделать ввод текста с клавиатуры  в игре (не только имени персонажа). Делать ввод по-другому - изобретения двухколесного транспортного средства с рулем и педалями. Что именно вы не поняли? Может быть, как получить текст из InputField? Его можно получить с помощью:

```
[Сам_объект-текстовое_поле].GetComponent<InputField>().text;
```

Если вам не понятно что-то другое - пишите, отвечу, но лучше для вас почитать документацию по ссылке в начале.

Comment: @JustTestingV, если вам помог мой ответ, то пожалуйста, нажмите на галочку, чтобы принять его. Это даст другим участникам сообщества понять, что вопрос закрыт, а я получу несколько баллов репутации за ответ на ваш вопрос. Также вы можете нажать стрелочку вверх, тем самым повысив мой ответ. Плюсом ко всему вопрос задан давно, так что вам вряд ли кто-то еще ответит

Comment: @JustTestingV еще раз напомню вам про необходимость принятия ответа

Answer (score 1):

Дополнение [ответу участника Максим Фисман](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1164710/324730).

---

Прежде чем просто взять значение с InputField я бы посоветовал проверить его:

```cs
using UnityEngine.UI;

...

[SerializedField] private InputField _JustAField;
private string _PlayerName;

private void Start()
{
    _JustAField.onValueChanged.AddEventListener
    {
        delegate(string value)
        {
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                _PlayerName = value;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Согласен, в данном случае проверить важно, так как игрок может ничего не ввести и попытаться принять свое имя! Спасибо за поправку, ну свой ответ тогда поправлять не буду, раз вы написали ваш! Но зачем добавлять `AddEventListener` в скрипте в Start(), если его можно указать прямо из редактора в компоненте InputField?

Answer (score -1):

Как написали выше, можно сделать это все через делегаты (GetComponent). Но я хочу предложить способ, легче, которым пользуюсь сам.
Необходимо создать переменную типа InputField, вот таким образом:

```
public InputField name;
```

Затем у этой переменной можно получить сам введенный в текстовое поле текст. Это и будет значение, которое введет игрок. Его можно записать в обычную переменную, вот таким образом:

```
string character_name = name.text;
```

Оба способа рабочие, но для меня, этот проще, ибо понятнее, пользуйтесь)

Comment: А в чем собственно разница? Разве что в том, что у меня есть переменная с GameObject, откуда мы получаем компонент InputField. А у вас переменная сразу типа InputField, НО ее все равно придется как-то получать: из скрипта путем того же GetComponent или из редактора - не важно. Плюс у меня можно взаимодействовать со всем объектом, а не просто с одним его компонентом. Так что странный у вас "простой и понятный" вариант

Comment: И кстати, `Затем у этой переменной будет компонент текст.` - у переменной типа InputFIeld не может быть компонента text, потому что InputField - это и так компонент объекта. А text - это не компонент, а поле компонента InputField

Comment: Касательно компонента вы правы, моя ошибка. Но я просто сам еще недавно учился, и прекрасно понимаю, что так будет проще. Было для меня, и для многих других, кому я помогал. Взаимодействовать можно не только с одним компонентом текст.

Comment: Чую, что где-то вас видел: посмотрел - вы отвечали на мой вопрос, про несколько тегов:))) Что вы имеете под будет проще? Что чуть короче: с объектом это `объект->компонент->текст`, а сразу с компонентом только `компонент->текст`? Но представьте, что нужно будет, например, получить позицию нашего InputField или, например, изменить его цвет в компоненте Image. Тогда придется идти по пути `Компонент InputField -> gameObject -> Компонент Image -> color`. Да и вообще компонент InputField все равно придется где-то задавать: в редакторе или скрипте. Так что... ну не знаю... будет [продолжение далее]

Comment: Что будет новичку легче: получить объект и у него доставать компоненты одной командой GetComponent, или взять компонент и в случае необходимости другого компонента получать gameObject и только потом получать компонент.

Comment: Может быть, вы и правы... Но как по мне, лучше знать оба способа, и выбрать тот, который вам по душе. Никогда не любил делегаты) Ну, вам есть, из чего выбирать, что очень хорошо.

Comment: Я не писал про делегаты, но я тоже их недопонимаю

Comment: Скобки такого типа <> - это всегда делегаты. Меня они тоже оч раздражают)

Comment: А нет, тогда меня это вообще не раздражает. Я думал вы про делегаты, которые в ответе пользователя Арман

Comment: Пользователь Арман использовал делегаты)

Comment: Эмм... И что? Вам не нравится сочетание "Пользователь Арман"? Я просто подумал, что это редкое имя, поэтому если я напишу "в ответе Армана" вы можете не понять

Comment: Да нет, проблем нет. Мы наверное неправильно друг друга поняли. В любом случае, если вы нашли ответ, я счастлив)